# jQuery or math to subtract pixels off div's using a percentage for width - jSfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/7fyvn/1/

Hello, this is a question I'm really struggling to find an answer for.

It may not be necessarily jQuery, it my be a simple bit of css.

I have created [jSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/7fyvn/1/) so you can experiment for yourself.

My circumstance is that I have a variable width container, called `div#container` in fiddle.

And inside this container, I have 2 columns. The column widths are determined by percentage.

Currently I have the left width at 65% and right at 35%, using additional `.left` & `.right` classes.

I would have the same problem even if I was using `width: 50%` on my `.column` class.

**My problem, is that I need a 10px margin between my 2 columns. Currently my column widths add up to a total of 100%, to fill the entire white box.**

**If I add 10px padding-right to my left column. Then the layout breaks, and the same happens with adding margin-right.**

**My question is, how can I subtract 5px from each of the column widths using jQuery or javascript? Whilst still keeping the percentage for my widths?**

Is this possible in some way or am I dreaming. Is it possible with javascript math? I can envisage it, but I can't think where to start, or what method is the safest and lightest.

It will be used on phone browsers, so when the orientation flips from landscape to portrait, the javascript subtraction needs to stay true whilst allowing the percentage widths to adjust.

Hope this makes sense, don't hesitate to ask me for more info.

---

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

See solved fiddle here just using css and an extra div... http://jsfiddle.net/7fyvn/4/

You can adjust the window size and gutter always stays the same, -20px off the left column. See classes `.new-div` and `.text-padding`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way would be to add:

```
$(document).ready(function () { /* standard jQuery document ready */
    $("div.white-box").each(function(){ /* not optimal, but allowing for each white box to be a different width on the page */
        var width = $(this).width(), /* get the width of the white-box */
            left = $(this).find("div.left"), /* find the left column */
            right = $(this).find("div.right"); /* find the right column */
        left.width((width - 10) * 0.65).css('padding-right','10px'); /* set the left column to 65% of total minus 10 pixels and then pad those pixels back on to provide spacing */
        right.width((width - 10) * 0.35); /* set the right column to 35% of what is left after taking 10 pixels away from the total */
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It works but the problem is when you flip landscape to portrait on device, the dimensions stay fixed. But this is good to know how to subtract pixels for browser based stuff :-) I fixed the problem with extra div's in the end. Thanks